Using Jest in Express works well when tests are run separately, but fails when they're run all together
I have a Node + Express application and I'm trying to test my endpoints with Jest.
I don't want to use Supertest, since its development doesn't seem to be very active (at the moment to post this their last commit was 5 months ago), so I'm trying to test my application with "Vanilla Jest".
I have the following files/code:
//positions.test.js
const { checkInvalidDatetime } = require("../helpers/tests");

test("Validation", async () => {
  await checkInvalidDatetime(
    {
      datetime: 8,
    },
    "datetime format is invalid"
  );
});

//positions2.test.js
const { checkInvalidDatetime } = require("../helpers/tests");

test("Validation", async () => {
  await checkInvalidDatetime(
    {
      datetime: 9,
    },
    "datetime format is invalid"
  );
});

//helpers/tests.js
const axios = require("axios");

const checkInvalidDatetime = async (params, expectedOutput) => {
  try {
    await axios.get("http://localhost:4500/positions", {
      params,
    });
  } catch ({ response }) {
    expect(response.status).toBe(404);
    expect(response.data).toBe(expectedOutput);
  }
};

module.exports = {
  checkInvalidDatetime,
};

Both tests work well and pass when I run them separately. However, when I run all the tests at once, sometimes positions.js passes and positions2 throws an error, whereas some other times the result is exactly the opposite: positions.js throws an error while positions2 passes.
The error thrown by the random test that fails is the following:
FAIL  src/__tests__/positions2.test.js
  ✕ Validation (41 ms)

  ● Validation

    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'status')

       7 |     });
       8 |   } catch ({ response }) {
    >  9 |     expect(response.status).toBe(404);
         |                     ^
      10 |     expect(response.data).toBe(expectedOutput);
      11 |   }
      12 | };

      at status (src/helpers/tests.js:9:21)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/__tests__/positions2.test.js:4:3)

Apparently, the failing test fails due the Axios request returns an ECONNRESET error. In some forums I have read that some people were able to solve a similar problem using --runInBand, but that approach never worked for me. How can I get rid of that error?
Update:
The problem might be something related to the opening and closing endpoints, since I'm also getting a listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::4500 error from the failing test. So here I share what I have on my jest.setup.js file:
const app = require("./src/app");
const server = app.listen(4500);

afterAll(() => {
  server.close();
});

I don't understand why there's a conflict between port numbers.

The problem could be caused by cross-test contamination but it doesn't look like the case here. You're losing info by prematurely destructuring an error, catch ({ response }). "Apparently, the failing test fails due the Axios request returns an ECONNRESET error" - is that certain? What you describe means that the server cannot handle multiple requests for some reason, this is specific to your app, check the logs. runInBand confirms this. "their last commit was 5 months ago" - this is not bad at all, it's far from being abandoned, feel free to use it if you believe this will help your testing

Thank you @EstusFlask, I think you're right, it must be a problem in my express app. And after fixing it I'll probably use supertest to make it easier

Notice that even without supertest you can keep express instance in your test with random port and add event handlers to it to get useful error in a test. This is roughly what supertest does. But then there may be a problem if multiple server instance are supposed to connect to the same db, for instance, so depending on what the app does, you may not be able to fully avoid cross-test contamination

@EstusFlask so maybe the error is being caused by something related what you're saying: random port numbers. I've just posted an update on my question regarding this, and might be a port conflict

Yes, that's likely it. It wasn't shown where localhost:4500 came from. In a situation like yours the server should've been started once before all test suite. It's not shown what jest.setup.js is, but it should be globalSetup, not setupFiles. That you have afterAll there suggests that currently it's not. Any way, this is something to keep in mind for the future, there'd be no such problems with supertest

Thank you again @EstusFlask, that approach works well

Finally I found why my tests were failing, thanks to the help coming from the user Estus Flask.
First than all, I should be using Supertest which makes this kind of tasks easier. But even in this approach, my mistake was that the server was set in a setupFilesAfterEnv config file...
//jest.config.js

const config = {
  /*...*/
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ["./jest.setup.js"],
};

module.exports = config;

//jest.setup.js

const app = require("./src/app");
const server = app.listen(4500);

afterAll(() => {
  server.close();
});

This approach opens a new server before all tests for each file. In other words, it doesn't open a new server before all tests in all files. Therefore, when I run the tests, there are two test files running at the same time opening a new server with the same port number (in this case 4500), which creates a conflict.
The solution was create the server in a globalSetup and close it in a globalTeardown as follows:
//jest.config.js

const config = {
  /* ... */
  globalSetup: "./jest.global.js",
  globalTeardown: "./jest.teardown.js",
};

module.exports = config;

//jest.global.js

const app = require("./src/app");

module.exports = async function (globalConfig, projectConfig) {
  const server = app.listen(4500);

  globalThis.__SERVER__ = server;
};


//jest.teardown.js

module.exports = async function (globalConfig, projectConfig) {
  globalThis.__SERVER__.close();
};


